# Fill in an array from a single formatted keyboard line in C

Tags: c, arrays, fill, keyboard-input, formatted-input

How can I fill in a double or int array from a single, arbitrarily long, formatted (e.g. space delimited) keyboard line?

For instance:

```
Enter the elements of the array:
2 32 12.2 4 5 ...
```

should result in

```
=> array[0] = 2
=> array[1] = 32 etc.
```

I know that I can use scanf as follows, but that does not solve my problem, since each element should be entered one by one.

```
  /* Input data from keyboard into array */

  for (count = 1; count < 13; count++)
  {
      printf("Enter element : %d: ", count);
      scanf("%f", &array[count]);
  }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Read in the entire string from the keyboard using `fgets`, then scan through the string - use `strtok` to find spaces, and finally interpret the "tokens" with `sscanf`.

Comment: *NEVER* use `gets()`! Read it in using `fgets()`, maybe. The `gets()` function is inherently, unfixably unsafe, and has been deprecated, excluded from the current version of the C standard, and marked Obsolete by POSIX.

Comment: You could enter a string of numbers comma separated such as "12.3,4.5,56.678, 12.1, 0.123" or as long as you want.  Then hit return, scanf it in as a string.  Use strtok to break it apart then use strtof() to convert the strings into floats, and assign them to a float array.

Comment: @Floris: You cannot be serious about recommending `gets`!

Comment: OK OK sorry typo guys. I fixed it. My point was really "get the line in the form of a string and parse it".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know that I can use scanf as follows, but that does not solve my problem, since each element should be entered one by one.

No. If you leave off the newlines, that would work perfectly fine.

---

Generally, it is a good idea to avoid using `scanf()`, though -- it's not the most intuitive function to use (so to say). How about using `fgets()` to read in the line then parse it using `strtof()`?

```
char buf[LINE_MAX];
fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);

char *s = buf, *endp;
int i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
    array[i] = strtof(s, &endp);
    s = endp;
}
```

Comment: Really? I don't think that you could type in a string of `1 2 3 4 5` followed by `CRLF`, and expect the above code to give you an array with the values 1 though 5 in it? Am I misinterpreting your answer, or the question?

Comment: @Floris I think you are misinterpreting both.

Comment: @H2CO3 - The drift of what you are communicating in your answer is fine, but it is not syntactically correct.  Floris' question has more merit than you give credit.

Comment: @ryyker Sorry, I don't understand what your problem is. OP thinks that one has to press Enter each time one wants `scanf()` to initiate a new conversion. I pointed out that it is not the case. I have even provided an alternative solution (which is similar to Floris' suggestion, just less complicated). I didn't say that Floris' comment was wrong either. I have honestly no idea what you are frowning upon...

Comment: @H2CO3 Would it be more efficient to have the loop condition be `i < 13 && *s != '\n'`?

Comment: @H2CO3 - Actually, I apologize, I did not recognize the syntax of the second argument of fgets, I have only seen it used as sizeof(arg).  My bad.  I learned yet another thing today- sizeof arg is syntactically correct.  Thanks.

Comment: @ryyker Well, no problem. We always learn new things every day. :)

Comment: @verbose Perhaps. I don't know. I can hardly be bothered to care about efficiency when accepting user input. I/O is so heavy and slow that iterating over the last few characters or not would not make a significant difference.

Comment: @verbose - regarding the loop condition, I am not sure if it would be more efficient, but I am pretty sure that including *s != '\n' would not be necessary given the OP question is asking how to do it without entering each time.  He wants to enter an _arbitrarily long, formatted (e.g. space delimited) keyboard line_

Comment: It would seem that the loop condition should be more like `ii<13 && s!=NULL` since the number of arguments is variable

Comment: I think strtof is not defined in VS 2010. Therefore I could not check this answer.

Comment: @H2CO3 how would you decide that the user actually put in all the elements (13 in this example), assuming that the user can also enter zeros ? I want to print an error if less than 13 elements are typed. strtod returns 0 when invalid (or insufficient) data is given.

Comment: @KaganOguz you have to check the `endp` which `strtod()` sets to point to one after the last processed number. If there aren't any digits after that, then that's the end of input.

Comment: @H2CO3 can you also tell me how to read integers, too. I couldn't succeed yet.

Comment: atoi() for reading string into int.  @H2CO3 (sorry for butting in :))

Comment: @ryyker Better use `strtol()` instead.

Comment: @KaganOguz You should search for that in the documentation.

Comment: @H2CO3 - Agreed, long int would be more prudent, but question was how to convert into int.  :)

Comment: @ryyker I know that very well. That's not about the width of the integer. If I mean "use long instead of int", then I write "use long instead of int". I didn't - I wrote "use `strtol()` instead of `atoi()`. It's just that one should avoid `atoi()` and prefer  `strtol()` to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have an array that will hold both `int` AND `double` values. You can either have an array of `int`, or an array of `double`. If there are likely to be any `double`s in your input, you should just declare an array of `double`.

You have to also set a maximum size for the array, and stop reading when that number of elements is filled. In C, you cannot have an array of dynamic size. If you really need to dynamically change the data structure based on the number of values, you're better off using a linked list.

`scanf()` is not a great tool for this, as it won't distinguish the newline at the end of the input from the space that separates numbers. Use `fgets()` to read the entire line and then `sscanf()` to split it into array elements.

Here's how to use the array:

```
double ary[MAX_ARRAY_SIZE];    // MAX_ARRAY_SIZE being some defined value
char buffer [512];
char* ptr = buffer;
int i = 0;

printf ("Enter your values separated by spaces: ");
fgets (buffer, sizeof (buffer), stdin);

while (i < MAX_ARRAY_SIZE && ptr) {
    sscanf (ptr, "%lf", &ary[i]);
    ptr++;
    i++;
    ptr = strchr(ptr, '\040');
}
```

Comment: Here is a working example of the code: http://ideone.com/SvyaF7. Note that the assumption is that only one space separates each value on the input line. If there are multiple spaces, this code won't work. @H2CO3's answer is more robust.

Comment: the error says "R6002 - floating point support not loaded". What am I missing ?

Comment: I couldn't check @H2CO3's answer, is strtof not defined in VS 2010?

Comment: With regard to @H2CO3's answer, you probably just need to `#include <stdlib.h>`. With regard to the R6002 error: http://runtimerrorfix.blogspot.com/2013/05/runtime-error-r6002-floating-point.html.

Comment: I have included stdlib.h but somehow it says strtof is undefined. No problem with strtod.

Comment: Is there any function that I can replace `strtod` when reading integers. There is `strtol`, but why no such thing as `strtoi` ?

Comment: `atoi()` does no error checking. `strtod()` is preferable for integers. Why do you need to replace it?

Comment: @verbose I did try to use it but I dont know why casting does not work in: `param[i] = (int)strtod(s, &endp);`. I get zeros in the array.

Comment: @verbose I sent it to you

Comment: Did you get it? Dont you mean your account is verbose ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do some work on variable initialization etc..  But this will do what you ask.

```
#include <ansi_c.h>

int main(void)
{
    char hold[20][10];
    double arr[20];//change size as necessary
    char *buf;
    char *toss;
    int i=-1, j=0;
    buf = malloc(260);
    toss = malloc(260);

    fgets(buf, 260, stdin);
    buf = strtok(buf, " ");
    while(buf)
    {
        strcpy(hold[++i], buf);
        arr[i] = strtod(hold[i], &toss);
        buf = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    for(j=0;j<i;j++)
    {
        printf("arr[%d]=%f\n", j, arr[j]);  
    }

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this code works fine. Just need to make (j<=i) in the last for loop to print all the elements in the array.